# Link biblioteca boost com cmake?

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, boost

Estou tentando usar biblioteca boost c++.
Lendo um tutorial no site deles, me deparei com isso e não sei como fazer.
É dito que eu tenho que incluir `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` e fazer um link com essa lib : libunit_test_framework.lib. Não quero usar a pré-copilada que é a opção que eles dão mais embaixo, quer poder fazer da primeira forma.
Como eu faço esse link com essa lib?

Fonte: [Boost Test Library Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/section_faq.html#boost_test.section_faq.where_the_latest_version_of_the_)

[image: Tutorial]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o módulo [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html), que vem na instalação padrão do CMake, pra incluir boost no seu projeto. A sintaxe é a seguinte:

```
find_package(Boost
  [version] [EXACT]      # Versão mínima ou exata (EXACT).
  [REQUIRED]             # Emita um erro se Boost não for encontrado.
  [COMPONENTS <libs>...] # Use bibliotecas específicas do Boost.
  )
```

Por exemplo, para usar Boost na versão exata *1.65.1*, pacote requerido para o build ser bem sucedido, com as bibliotecas *Filesystem*, *Regex* e *Algorithm*:

```
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem regex)
```

Se o pacote do boost for encontrado e sua versão bater com a especificada, então a biblioteca ficará disponível para ser usada no resto do seu CMakeLists.txt, através do namespace `Boost::`.

O leitor atencioso notará que não há menção da biblioteca *Algorithm* acima. Como essa biblioteca tem a característica de ser *header-only* (implementada toda em um cabeçalho), não existe um componente pra ser requerido, pois não há nada para construir e linkar. Incluindo o cabeçalho já é suficiente. Você pode linkar o alvo `Boost::boost` no alvo da sua aplicação e os diretórios de inclusão serão adicionados automaticamente.

Por exemplo, o seguinte `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(ProjetoExemplo)
include(FindBoost)
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem regex)
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::filesystem Boost::regex)
```

Compilando o simples exemplo a seguir como `main.cpp`:

```
#include "boost/algorithm/cxx11/none_of.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
#include "boost/regex.hpp"

int main() {}
```

Executando os seguintes comandos:

```
cmake .
cmake --build .
```

Deverá gerar um executável chamado `app`. Note que as inclusões dos cabeçalhos do boost são feitas usando `"..."` e não `<...>`. Isso porque os diretórios de inclusão são passados pro compilador pelo CMake, então é melhor usá-los dessa maneira.